# Find double defined functions in PHP

Tags: php, function, static-analysis, duplicates

I work in a php project with multiple independent developers and recently we had case where a function getmicrotime() was twice defined.

all worked fine, because they were defined in different files that were not both included in a single call ... until some refactory.

in the standardcase php would just output a fatal error, but here the output was blocked. (because a thirdparty website called a website ...) so we did not get the output, just the information that nothing worked anymore.

To the point: 
Is there any method, external script, etc to check if functions with the same name are defined twice in the project?

i thought about reg. expr search, but ofcourse class methods can have the same name like a::meth1 and b:meth1 .... so its not that easy.

i am talking about a project with ~100.000 lines of ugly code ... so manual checking is not possible

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's external tools such as [phpcpd](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpcpd) which look for duplicated blocks of code, or you could write your own lexer; but functions with duplicated names are perfectly valid in PHP as long as they're differently namespaced

Answer (score 0):

Consider static code analysis. I would suggest Sonar + PHP plugin: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Plugin

Here is the life example how it works: 
http://nemo.sonarqube.org/dashboard/index/net.php.pear.phpcodesniffer

You can always write a simple script (i.e. perl or python) which will find all duplicates. The algorithm would be simple...